# List files in multiple branches of a repo using one looping script

Tags: bash, git

Use case: A build of a documentation website produces an `index.json` file, which lists every page in the website. Source files are in a Git repo. Each "section" of the site (e.g., `{url}/section-1`, `{url}/section-2`) is populated by a matching branch of the repo. For each branch/site section, I want a list of the included web pages to process in a looping Bash script.

In simplified form:

```
for branch in \
section-1 \
section-2 \
section-3 ; do

git checkout $branch

# Get website source files
git pull

# Build website to produce index.json for that branch (this is already coded)

# Transform index.json of that branch to a CSV (this is already coded)

done

# Concat the CSV for each branch into a master CSV (this is already coded)
```

This works (most of the time - sometimes an `Aborted` message is shown, or `The git repository at 'c:\Source\repo' has too many active changes, only a subset of Git features will be enabled`) but I feel like the way I'm using Git here may not be optimal. Is anyone aware of pitfalls I may be opening myself up to, or a smarter solution? Thank you if so.

Comment: There is no need to check out a branch if all you want to know is the names of the files it contains. But of course you _do_ need to check out a branch if you want to do something with those files, such as a build a web site out of them. What I really want to know is why it was a good idea to have _branches_ stand for _sections of a web site_.

Comment: @matt How would I get that though, in a script? I may be missing something obvious

Comment: Maybe I'm the one who is missing something. I'm just thinking how a human would do it. First of all, where is the source of truth? Is it your local git, or is it the remote? If it's the remote, `git fetch`; now everything is up to date. Now just cycle thru the remote-tracking branches that stand for sections of the web site and, for each one, do a `git ls-tree` to get the pathnames of all the files it contains. — But maybe when you say you want to "list every file" you mean something I'm not grasping.

Comment: Thanks for the follow ups. The source of truth is remote. Originally my thought was that I would need the files locally to build the website and retrieve the index file it produces. But using `ls-tree` may accomplish the same thing or close to it. Thanks for offering a better way.

Comment: When you say `fetch` you have the files locally (in the remote tracking branches of of the local repo).